# add data to array/object via form javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form. If you fill in the form, the data must be placed in the constant USERS with (vanilla) javascript. Can somebody help me, please?

It is also intended that the CONST USERS will be shown in the div 'show', but doesn't have to.

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Users</title>
</head>
<body>


<main>
    <form>
        <label for="ordername">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>

        <label for="age">Age:</label>
        <input type="number" id="age" name="age"/>

        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit"/>
    </form>

    <div class="show">

    </div>
</main>

<script>
    const USERS = [
    {
        name: Brit,
        age: 45,

    },
    {
        name: John,
        age: 55,
    }];

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is Java relevant here?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this homework on your own?

Answer (score 0):

in your code `const = USERS` is also not a valid. read syntax before use.

**You can push as below**

```js
const USERS = [];
    
var form_el = document.getElementById("myForm");

form_el.addEventListener("submit", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
   var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
   var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
   var objsingle = {};
   objsingle.name = name;
   objsingle.age = age;
   USERS.push(objsingle);
   
   //console.log(USERS);
   document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(USERS);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Users</title>
</head>
<body>


<main>
    <form id="myForm">
        <label for="ordername">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>

        <label for="age">Age:</label>
        <input type="number" id="age" name="age"/>

        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit"/>
    </form>

    <div class="show" id="show">

    </div>
</main>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a special reason for `objsingle` and using the dot notation instead of just pushing an object directly: `.push({ name: ..., age: ...})`?

Comment: Oh I forgot to say if I leave the website again that the data will remain on the webpage.

Comment: @TProgroam then you ned to store data in localstorage or cookies.

Answer (score 0):

- In your code with the provided users example, you have `name: Brit` and `name: John`, They should be strings like, `name: "Brit"`, and `name: "John"`.
- In your comment `"Oh I forgot to say if I leave the website again that the data will remain on the webpage"` do you mean using something like `localstorage` ?

The following snippet should do it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Users</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <form id="user-form">
      <label for="ordername">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>

      <label for="age">Age:</label>
      <input type="number" id="age" name="age"/>

      <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit"/>
    </form>

    <div class="show"></div>
  </main>

  <script>
    const users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users") || "[]");
    console.log(users);

    const form = document.getElementById("user-form");
    form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const name = document.getElementById("name").value;
      const age = document.getElementById("age").value;
      const user = { name, age };
      users.push(user);

      localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users));
      console.log(users);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```